# If React Native apps should be 'offline first' how do you manage an AWS / RDS database?

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, react-native

Pretty new to app development (and everything) but i put a MySQL database into an web app we built on a bootcamp.

Now i'm working on a personal project that pulls in local concert/gig data for the day of the week. Obviously this would require a database.

I was thinking:
User clicks on day > API call to database > json comes back, is fed into components.

But a) i can find little-to-no documentation/tutorials on how to get that happening & b) the idea my app has to be available "offline first" has thrown me a bit.

Can anyone recommend a good blog or tutorial on that model?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to tackle this problem but I'd recommend you have a look at PouchDB/CouchDB. Essentially, you'd be committing to your local PouchDB, keeping your local store up to date and working offline. When there's connectivity, PouchDB will sync with any other CouchDB for online persistence. The nice thing about the Pouch/Couch pairing is that syncing is taken care of for you, which is a non-trivial problem.

Firebase also takes care of the offline experience. There's a mini-mongo used by Meteor as well. And probably many others, but this is probably the way you'll want to go.